# Gif image sometimes not showing

Tags: php, jquery, image, gif

I'm using PHP 5.3, IIS 7 to host my web page. I also have this Jquery code below which should populate the html content whenever a button is clicked.

```
 $("#loader").fadeIn(500).
                    html('Generating report... <img src="/image/loading.gif" /> ');
```

Problem - sometimes the image itself doesn't load, sometimes it loads successfully, however the text 'Generating report...' always showed. 
This problem happens intermittently. I don't know what could be the cause as the image link is definitely valid.

Comment: Use Firebug or similar Dev Tools in the browser to see network activity and if the problem is server-side related.

Comment: network activity is fine

Comment: Your question is really hard to answer then. Check your php, is there any problems in your code there? Is this problem occuring in all browsers? Have you tried this issue on another network (if possible)? You only answering **'network activity is fine'** tangents that you dont like to embody your question nor answers with details. :-/

Comment: I only have one network for the meantime. If the code is incorrect, the 'Generating report..' text shouldn't be showing at all. I have mentioned that this is intermittent, so the risk of anything wrong with my code is low.

Comment: I have also tried using a different image and using an http image link instead. Still the same occurs

Comment: You should consider error handling or try defining a preLoader function that works something like this: `function preLoader() { loadingImage = new Image(); loadingImage.src = "../image/loading.gif"; }` and call it on your `<body onLoad>` event.